# Lack of Proper Ending in Stories by Old Indian Authors

Tags: history-of-literature, hindi-language, urdu-language

I have read quite a few stories by old Indian authors who wrote in Hindi and Urdu in the early twentieth century.

I noticed a trend of them not completing their stories or providing an ending and leaving their audience in a mystery which often is quite a let down especially after reading a 10 page story.

For instance the author [Mithileshwar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mithileshwar) wrote a story by the title of *Harihar Kaka* depicting the plight of an old man, however didn't provide an ending as to what happened to him.

Or [Premchand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premchand)'s famous *Bade Bhai Sahab* which also didn't provide what happened in the future of the two brothers.

Is there a reason for this trend among Indian authors?

Comment: I think it's worth inspecting more closely why you believe these stories do not have a "proper" ending. Likely they ended exactly as the author intended, and if you're finding this to be a pattern it's plausible that the ending is in fact "proper" for that (equally-legitimate) way of telling stories. So, more precisely: what are you looking for in your version of a proper ending that you're not finding?

Comment: @Aza for instance most of the stories leave the plot at a cliffhanger for instance in one the stories the man is shown to be living alone in the end while in the other the two brother run towards their home together which doesn't tell one about how the future of the characters unfolded